# Breaking a loop while input blank line

Tags: c++, loops, break

I have a function like this, all what I want is to break a loop if pa[i].fullname is a blank line. Tried some ways, still didn't find the soluting. 
I am going along with Stephen Prata book, and this is one of exercises.
Would be glad for some tips.

```
int getinfo(student pa[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Imie: " << endl;
        cin >> pa[i].fullname;
        cout << "Hobby: ";
        cin >> pa[i].hobby;
        cout << "Ooplevel: ";
        cin >> pa[i].ooplevel;
    [enter link description here][1]
        }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `if (pa[i].fullname.empty()){ break; }` Assuming fullname is std::string.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/jufukofaji.cpp
here is rest of code, couldn't figure out code formatting on this site yet, sorry I am making this this way

Comment: @TrevorHickey Um... even if that were a `std::string` that won't work as a general solution. The extraction operator will skip whitespace, including newlines, until a stream failure or actually reads a non-empty string. I think a proper solution uses `std::getline` rather than stream extraction, and of course, the OP should actually be checking all the IO operations anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig ofc I will, but at first I want to focus on make it as exercise says, than try to make it better `getline(cin, pa[i].fullname)` will work?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pa[i] == null)
    break;
```

you can try this ..

Comment: Please add additional information to your answer to explain why this would help.